# discord.py /say more than one word

Tags: python, discord

so I'm trying to make a /say command for my discord bot. The /say command makes the bot say what you said before e.g `person: /say hi` `bot: hi`

So far I've made it work but it can only say one word: `person: /say hello world` `bot: hello`

so how do I make it so that it can say more than one word?
here's my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')

@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, string: str):
    await ctx.send(string)


bot.run('Token')
```

Comment: say(ctx, *, string:str)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When passing in arguments to a discord bot, it takes each argument one at a time.

For example if I were to write the following command function:

```
async def add(ctx, num1: int, num2: int):
```

Then it would only take in the first two arguments I pass into it, for example

```
/add 1 2
```

When passing in an unknown amount of arguments, you must use *args, the key for variadic arguments in python.

If you change your function to

```
async def say(ctx, *args):
    string = ' '.join(args)
```

Then it will work as expected. This takes in the rest of the arguments passed into the command and joins them together with spaces.